# Returning array from d3.json()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

As a JQUERY/d3-noob, it seems I cannot figure out how to make this work:

```
  supdog = d3.json(dataPath, function(jsondata){
    return jsondata;
  })
  console.log(supdog);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Besides the fact that your problem description is very terse, the problem seems to be your assumptions about what is returning what.

The function d3.json() is an asynchronous function that directly returns (with an undefined value I assume). Only when the data is received from the backend, the callback function you passed to it will be called. Obviously the context is different here and the return value of your callback will not automatically become the return value of d3.json (as this one has returned "long" before already).

What you want to do is probably something like:

```
    var jsondata;
    d3.json(dataPath, function(dataFromServer) {
      jsondata = dataFromServer;
    }
    console.log(jsondata);
```

**Update 1:**
Obviously, the above example is still not fully correct. The call to console.log() is made directly after the d3.json() returned. Thus, the server might not have sent the reply fully yet. Therefore, you can only access data when the callback is returned. Fixed example:

```
    var jsondata;

    function doSomethingWithData() {
      console.log(jsondata);
    }

    d3.json(dataPath, function(dataFromServer) {
      jsondata = dataFromServer;
      doSomethingWithData();
    })
```

For a (somewhat stupid, but) working example see: http://jsfiddle.net/GhpBt/10/

**Update 2:**
The above example demonstrates in which order the code is executed but does not really deserve a price for most beautiful code. I myself would not use this "global" variable and simplify the above example to:

```
    function doSomethingWithData(jsondata) {
      console.log(jsondata);
    }

    d3.json(dataPath, doSomethingWithData);
```

Note how doSomethingWithData is directly passed to d3.json in stead of calling it separately in an anonymous inner function.

**Note:** This is not a particular problem of d3.js. Basically, all javascript functions that are asynchronous are likely to behave in a similar way. If they return something, it will not be the return value of the passed callback.

Comment: Are you sure that you actually get a result? I.e. could you try to put the console.log() in the function body (and put the dataFromServer in there). Also, a minimal example demonstrating the problem on jsfiddle.net will help to understand what you're exactly doing.

Comment: yep, an array is given as a result inside the function

Comment: Let me add that there is a small syntax error in your first code: the d3.json call is lacking a closing parenthesis. I don't have the reputation to make an edit with only a few characters missing.

Answer (score 3):

Solutions do not work anymore, if you start with the current d3 version. New solution -> [Code within d3.json() callback is not executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768165/code-within-d3-json-callback-is-not-executed)

Then it must be...

```js
d3.json("filename.json")
  .then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Comment: Sometimes links get stale or broken and can't be followed later.  Can you summarize the information provided in the link in case it doesn't work in the future?

Comment: Thanks a lot! this works

Comment: how to assign now to variable to perform filters or analysis on?

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware that this is a very old post, but I've faced a similar problem recently, and found the following solution, which might worth sharing:

In my case the JSON file's syntax was broken. By default, no errors pop up in the browser in this case, unless you enhance the function suggested by @BertjanBroeksema with errorhandling. Something like this:

```
function doSomethingWithData(error, jsondata) {
  console.log("error:", error)
  console.log(jsondata);
}
```

This way you'll see if there was something wrong with the processing of the JSON file.