# d3.json console.log returns undefined or JSON.parse returns unexpected character at line 1

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, d3.js, console

I spend a lot of time trying to solve the errors from this statement to show the content of the json url in the console.log:

```
d3.json( urlpathtojson, function(error, jsondata ) {
    var jsonfile = JSON.parse(jsondata);
    console.log(jsonfile);
    }):
```

I could see the GET statement and the contents of the JSON request, but the console gave following error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

Or in other cases without parsing:

```
ReferenceError: jsondata is not defined
```

Or

```
jsondata is undefined
```

Below is the answer which I found on Stackoverflow. Hopefully it will help someone else as well.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It's a solution, possible for others to use, or do you know how can I add such a solution post more properly?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the console log statement runs without waiting for the return of the json file which results in above errors.

Through Stackoverflow I found this solution from this question:
[Returning array from d3.json()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656580/returning-array-from-d3-json)

```
function doSomethingWithData(jsondata) {
  console.log(jsondata);
}

d3.json(dataPath, doSomethingWithData);
```

**Note** how doSomethingWithData is directly passed to d3.json in stead of calling it separately in an anonymous inner function.

**Note:** This is not a particular problem of d3.js. Basically, all javascript functions that are asynchronous are likely to behave in a similar way. If they return something, it will not be the return value of the passed callback.

Comment: did you really take the post you have that was not a question but an explanation, then edit your post to a question and answer it?