# d3.json getting data is undefined

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am using URL in d3.json function, the data is showing undefined.

```
    My code here
    ==============
    var jsonURL = "http://192.168.7.102:8080/restful/traffic/json/get";

    d3.json(jsonURL, function(error, data){

    alert(data);
 });
```

When it is executed data is showing undefined. I created restful web service application to get the data using above URL it returns JSONArray.

## Application Code

```
@GET
    @Path("/json/get")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public JSONArray startReading() throws JSONException {

        String json = null;
        String newJson = null;

        try {

            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.7.102:3000/data/traffic");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

            while ((json = br.readLine()) != null) {
                newJson = json;

            }

            conn.disconnect();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(newJson);

        return array;

    }
```

When I access the URL in the browser data is displaying. But in d3.json function it is showing undefined instead of data. Due to that, I am not able to display the graph in the browser. Please guide me where I was doing wrong.

Comment: If your webpage is not on the same host (192.168.7.102:3000), make sure you have cross origin requests enabled.

Comment: I am using same IP address in the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data;

d3.json("http://192.168.7.102:8080/restful/traffic/json/get", function(error, json) {
  if (error) return console.warn(error);
  data = json;
  visualizeit();
});
```

Have a look at - https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests

Comment: when I execute alert(json); it is showing undefined instead of objects.

Comment: did you check data type of json file. is it still html or json ?
header('Content-Type: application/json');

Comment: check also this one may be helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656580/returning-array-from-d3-json