# Code within d3.json() callback is not executed

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to load a GeoJSON file and to draw some graphics using it as a basis with D3 **v5**.

The problem is that the browser is skipping over everything included inside the `d3.json()` call.  I tried inserting breakpoints to test but the browser skips over them and I cannot figure out why.

Code snippet below.

```
d3.json("/trip_animate/tripData.geojson", function(data) {

  console.log("It just works");  // This never logs to console.

  //...all the rest
}
```

The code continues on from the initial `console.log()`, but I omitted all of it since I suspect the issue is with the `d3.json` call itself.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

The signature of [`d3.json`](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch#json) has [changed](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#changes-in-d3-50) from D3 v4 to v5. It has been moved from the now deprecated module d3-request to the new [d3-fetch](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch) module. As of v5 D3 uses the [Fetch API](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) in favor of the older `XMLHttpRequest` and has in turn adopted the use of [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to handle those asynchronous requests.

The second argument to `d3.json()` no longer is the callback handling the request but an optional [`RequestInit`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#requestinit) object. `d3.json()` will now return a Promise you can handle in its [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method.

Your code thus becomes:

```
d3.json("/trip_animate/tripData.geojson")
  .then(function(data){
    // Code from your callback goes here...
  });
```

Error handling of the call has also changed with the introduction of the Fetch API. Versions prior to v5 used the first parameter of the callback passed to `d3.json()` to handle errors:

```
d3.json(url, function(error, data) { 
  if (error) throw error;
  // Normal handling beyond this point.
});
```

Since D3 v5 the promise returned by `d3.json()` will be rejected if an error is encountered. Hence, vanilla JS methods of handling those rejections can be applied:

1. Pass a rejection handler as the second [argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Parameters) to `.then(onFulfilled, onRejected)`.
2. Use [`.catch(onRejected)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) to add a rejection handler to the promise.

Applying the second solution your code thus becomes

```
d3.json("/trip_animate/tripData.geojson")
  .then(function(data) {
    // Code from your callback goes here...
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // Do some error handling.
  });
```

Comment: @Timmmm, the .then method can be provided with an optional second function, one that is called if the promise ends up unfulfilled: `.then(function(data) {}, function(error) {})`

Comment: @Timmmm Alternatively, you can use `.catch(function(error) {})`, which is mostly equivalent to Andrew's proposal yet more verbally explicit.

Comment: Assume we can't use the V5 syntax, and must use V4. What are we supposed to do then ?

Comment: @3xCh1_23 You just use the original code as posted in the question.

Comment: @altocumulus does not work, that was the point... but found a workaround, which is a bit more complicated to share...

Answer (score -1):

Since none of the answers helped, I had to find the solution on my own that works. I am using v4 and have to stick with it. The problem was (in my case) that d3.json worked the first time, but did not work the second or third time (with a HTML dropdown).

The idea is to use the initial function, and then simply to use a second function with

**let data = await d3.json("URL");**

instead of

**d3.json("URL", function(data) {**

Therefore, the general pattern becomes:

```
async function drawWordcloudGraph() {
    let data = await d3.json("URL");
    ...
}


function initialFunction() {
    d3.json("URL", function (data) {
        ...
    });
}

initialFunction();
```

I have tried several approaches, and only this worked. Not sure if it can be simplified, please test on your own.