# D3 v5 can't render map properly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I'm a newbie in `D3.js`. I'm trying to create a map of Madrid neighbourhoods. I created a `,json` from a `.shp`.

The problem is **1)** when I want to use `D3.v5` I can't see anything; and **2)** when I use `D3.v4` my map is too small and in the bottom left corner of the SVG. I have [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sf3hn4w9/)  with the v4 version.

Thank you.

Comment: d3v5 uses promises for d3.json (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49768165/7106086)), so you need to change that when upgrading to v5. For sizing, this is the result of the parameters you have chosen, you could use: `projection.fitSize([width,height],geojson)` to set the projection paramaters based on the geographic features themselves: http://jsfiddle.net/0241kdty/

Comment: @AndrewReid, just wonder why haven't you answered this question? Your comment solves all problems above.

Comment: @AndrewReid Thank you so much! That solves my problem. I'm still learning `javascript` and `d3.js and sometimes I find myself lost in the examples. If you answer the question I'll accept it. Thank you