# D3 Force directed graph breaking change between v4 and v5?

Tags: d3.js, d3-force-directed

I'm new to D3 and looking at one of the [examples](https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/8a4e4e2fed281ea5e2a5c804a9a03783/85ced3ea82a4bed20a2010530562b655d8f6e464) for the force directed graph.

This example was built using v4, so the only update I'm making is to change from v4:

`<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>`

to v5:

`<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>`

However now nothing shows.

I've read where there were significant differences between v3 to v4, but [here](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md) it states: "D3 5.0 introduces only a few non-backwards-compatible changes" and among those I don't see anything mentioned about the force directed graph.

Was there a breaking change in v5 that would have this affect?

Where could I update this code to show the graph under v5?

Comment: Nothing breaks a force layout itself from v4 to v5 - but how you load the data has changed, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49769027/7106086).

Comment: Ah, got it.  Thanks for the point in the right direction!